# With which countries does Canada have reciprocal health agreements?

Tags: canada, international-travel, health, insurance

Is there a list somewhere? Please notify me  if it is the provinces that are responsible, because I know that the provincial, and not the federal, government operates healthcare for Canadians.

Comment: I don't see why people are voting to close this as off-topic on grounds of only being relevant to long stays. Reciprocity of healthcare agreements is highly relevant to short-term travelers. Anybody can fall ill or have an accident while traveling.

Comment: @DavidRicherby +1. Thank you for your support.

Comment: I'm not certain enough of this to make it an answer, but I believe there are none. All the most likely candidates - UK, EU, Australia, don't have them and US obviously doesn't. Does anyone except EU have these agreements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer to your question is none, but only when asking about Canada, that is, at the federal level. Health insurance in Canada comes under provincial [jurisdiction](http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/united_kingdom-royaume_uni/consular_services_consulaires/health-sante.aspx?lang=eng) so it's up to each province to determine how they cover you abroad.

That said, provinces don't have individual agreements with countries but rather they're required to provide care at the home [rate](http://www.hc-sc.gc.ca/hcs-sss/medi-assur/faq-eng.php#a9) and may not cover [everything](https://travel.gc.ca/travelling/publications/bon-voyage-but#insure).

> When outside the country, coverage is required to be at
>   home-province/territory rates. As a result, health care services
>   received abroad may not be fully covered by a provincial or
>   territorial health insurance plan

See [here](http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/united_kingdom-royaume_uni/emergency_services_urgences/insurance-assurance.aspx?lang=eng) for a list of provincial health websites, and a couple of examples of what [Alberta](http://www.health.alberta.ca/AHCIP/coverage-outside-Canada.html) and [Ontario](http://www.health.gov.on.ca/en/public/programs/ohip/outofcountry/) provide for you outside the country.

Comment: Saskatchewan has capped out-of-country coverage at C$100/day for many years.